# reverse tail for gnuplot

Tags: output, gnuplot, reverse

I would like to display data in a repeated online diagram with:

```
plot "tail -140 logging.dat | tac -r" with lines
```

I get an error message file cannot be opened, however in `CLI` it gives the reverse list of data as expected. Could anyone help me with the correct syntax, please?

Comment: Add `<` before `tail`

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records, here is a *gnuplot-only*, hence platform-independent solution. Check via `stats` the total number of lines. If there are less than `N` lines (here: 140), all lines will be plotted, otherwise only the 140 last ones.

Remark: if you do `plot ... with lines`, gnuplot will plot column 1 as x and column 2 as y per default. However, the output graph will look the same whether you reverse the data or not. So, I don't see why reversing the data would be necessary, unless you want to plot something what you haven't shown here or e.g. list a reversed table as text.

**Script:**

```
### plot N last lines of a file
reset session

FILE = "SO55221113.dat"

# create some random test data
set table FILE
    set samples 1000
    y0 = rand(0)
    plot '+' u 1:(y0=y0+rand(0)-0.5)
unset table

N = 140
stats FILE u 0 nooutput     # get total number of lines into STATS_records
M = STATS_records<=N ? STATS_records : STATS_records-N

plot FILE u 1:2           w l lc rgb "green" ti "all values", \
       '' u 1:2 every ::M w l lc rgb "red"   ti sprintf("last %d values",N)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]